# XYZ DaVinci 3D Printer constantly jamming

Tags: extruder, xyz-da-vinci-mini-w

I have an XYZ DaVinci Mini w which keeps jamming. It does not give a Jam Error. I disassembled the extruder 1 time and found a short piece of PLA stuck in it however that did not fix anything. I've also tried using the Load Filament function repeatedly to try to get the filament out but it does not work. However, after disassembling the extruder, instead of just not printing it makes a loud repeated clicking sound.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clicking sound typically means the drive gears are slipping on the filament because there is a jam in the head/nozzle.
First thing to do is clear the nozzle. You can use a small drill bit to clear the chamber, but if the extrusion hole (at the tip) is clogged, you'll need to get a set of fine wires designed for extruder clearing.  Then heat the head above melting point and slip the wire in (if possible).

In general, I find it easier and faster to replace clogged nozzles.  They're cheap, and more often than not clearing the exit hole enlarges the diameter (bad thing).